# Flash builder crashes with auto complete

Tags: apache-flex, autocomplete, crash

I've been working with Flash Builder for quite a long time, but just lately, developing a relative small project in Flex, when I try to auto complete the code sometimes the whole application crashes (keeps loading forever). It happened when I was writing `<Style source="" />` or even when it was auto generating an handler for an event, so I guess it doesn't depend on the classes I use.
Any suggestion?
thank you

Comment: do you include any heavy library or framework?

Comment: just the usual, the as3corelib and a flipbook component..I've had bigger projects in the past, that's why I was wondering if there was another reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Mac OSX, use this file :

`/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.5/Adobe Flash Builder 4.5.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Flash Builder 4.5.ini`

You will also need to recreate your workspace (delete .metadata folder).

You might be interested by this article : http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/2011/09/improving-flash-builders-performance.html

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a dead thread, but I'll answer where the eclipse.ini is on Windows Machines:

In your `Program Files` directory (`Program Files (x86)` if you're running 64-bit) and then in the following folders:
`\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\eclipse\eclipse.ini`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Locate your `eclipse.ini` file and set the following settings to higher values than you have right now.

```
-Xms600m
-Xmx800m
```

Comment: I can't find any file called like that, is it specific to Eclipse? I'm using Flash Builder 4 on Leopard 10.6.6